# linux mmap - how to recognize any access to it

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I've written a simple character dev module for Linux kernel to learn how mmap works. I've written simple "fault" handler for vm_operations_struct. But now I'm wondering how does mmap really works. If application hits some mmapped address for the first time - my "fault" handler should be invoked. But if this application hits the address for mapped area for the second and next time - it shouldn't raise any "fault" because this area is already mapped? Am I right or not?

Assuming that I've got some virtual device (not physical) how can I recognize any access to mmapped area from the driver point of view?

Is there any kind of trigger which tell me that now is the R/W access to mmapped area?

Comment: The mmap function returns a pointer so you should know the mapped address range. What is the additional benefit to trigger an event for every R/W?

Comment: R/W would be needed in another kind of driver - for example in proxy (virtual) framebuffer. I also asked those questions because I'd like to know when someone has written anything to proxy fb to rotate it or do something else and then send it to real framebuffer.